# Roots in Mathematica

Tags: arithmetic

Example:

x = (-8)^(1/3)

Return:

2 (-1)^(1/3)

How simplifying?

I need an answer as x = -2

Thanks!

Comment: $-1$ has three roots; *Mathematica*'s choice (the "principal branch") happens to be complex. You'll want to use `Surd[]` for real-valued odd roots of negative numbers. See the linked thread for more details.

Comment: Excuse me! I read properly but not fluent in English to explain properly...

Comment: @J.M. thanks por your answer!